# How to parse windows directory addresses in R?

Tags: r, directory, path, escaping

In R, while parsing a windows directory address or in general parsing a text string with backstrokes throws the following error:

```r
> 'C:\Users'
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
```

How to parse such strings?

Answer (score 3):

With R>4.0.0, it is possible to parse such strings with following syntax:

```r
> r"(C:\Users)"
[1] "C:\\Users"
```

Note that, `()` are part of syntax. For simplicity, one can also use `r"{...}"` and `r"[...]"`